# Differentiate $y = \arccos( sin( x ) )$

Tags: trigonometry, derivatives

I have found a different solution, so not urgent, I just can't make the solution below work completely:

Using a right angled triangle, let $\sin(x) = a/c$ --> opposite over hypotenuse.

$y = \arccos(a/c) =$ the remaining angle in the triangle $= \pi/2 - x$.

Accounting for the multiple solutions possible from $\arccos, y = \pi/2 - x + 2k\pi$ or $y = x - \pi/2 + 2k\pi$ where $k$ is an integer.

In these cases $dy/dx = -1$ and $dy/dx = 1$.

My issue is with identifying for which values of x the two equations apply. I know (from looking at the graph) that the first applies between $-\pi/2$ and $\pi/2 (+2k\pi)$ and the other between$\pi/2$ and $3\pi/2 (+2k\pi)$, but I don't know how to argue it from the information given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be done with the chain rule, since we have functions $f(x) = \arccos(x)$ and $g(x) = \sin(x)$ and we are interested in $y'(x) = [f(g(x))]'=f'(g(x)) \cdot g'(x)$. We know $$\arccos(x)' = \frac{-1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$ so if we plug in $\sin(x)$ in place of $x$ into the above equation we will get $$\arccos(\sin(x))'=  \frac{-1}{\sqrt{1-\sin^2(x)}}$$ Now if we multiply the above equation by the derivative of $g(x) = \sin(x)$, we will have pattern matched are answer to $y'$. Thus, $$y'(x) = \arccos(\sin(x))' \cdot \sin(x)' \\ =  \frac{-1}{\sqrt{1-\sin^2(x)}} \cdot \cos(x)$$ Further, you may be interested to take advantage of the identity $$1-\sin^2(x) = \cos^2(x)$$

Comment: This was the other solution I mentioned, I was just hoping to figure out the missing element in the argument I was using above...

Comment: I feel like it is easier to gather this information from the derivative above. $x$ cannot equal $\pm \frac{\pi}{2}$ because that will result in division by zero. This means $y$ is not differentiable at those points. other than those two points, everything inside the root has to be a positive quantity, which means the quantity $\frac{-1}{\sqrt{1-\sin^2(x)}}$ is always negative. We know $\cos(x)$ is positive for all $x \in (\frac{-\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$ so it follows that $\frac{-1}{\sqrt{1-\sin^2(x)}}\cos(x)$ is negative for all in $x \in (\frac{-\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$ and positive otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

it is just
$-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\sin(x)^2}}\cos(x)$

Comment: You forgot -Sonnhard.

Comment: I think that a bit of explanation of how you got the result would be helpful...

Comment: My other solution involved this - differentiating using the chain rule and the fact that dy/dx = 1/(dx/dy), but I was hoping to be able to finish the logic I started using above...